# PHP collect all rows from table

Tags: php, html

How can I make this php script repeat for the amount of rows within the table? I am a bit lost as how to start, thanks again.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxx", "xxx");

//    Check    connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed    to    connect    to    MySQL:    " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT    *    FROM    caseStudies");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++)
    {
    echo "<div    class='case'    id='case$i'>";
    echo "<div    class='row'>";
    echo "<div    class='header'>";
    echo '<h4>' . $row['caseName'] . '</h4>';
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div    class='row'>";
    echo "<div    class='caseimg'>";
    echo '<img    src="' . $row['caseImage'] . '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div    class='caseimg'>";
    echo '<img    src="' . $row['caseImage'] . '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div    class='caseimg'>";
    echo '<img    src="' . $row['caseImage'] . '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of: `$row    =    mysqli_fetch_array($result);
for($i    =    0;    $i    <    1;    $i++)    {` use `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {}` then your code. This will run as long as there are rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your condition in the forloop is not correct. use:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo ...
    $i++; //if you need $i
}
```

instead

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [**mysqli_num_rows**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) and [**mysqli_fetch_assoc()**](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc)

Try this :-

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM caseStudies");

$ispresent = @mysqli_num_rows($result);    

$i = 0;

if($ispresent > 0) // if row present then only run your while loop
{
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    
        echo    "<div    class='case'    id='case$i'>";
            echo    "<div    class='row'>";
            echo    "<div    class='header'>";
            echo    '<h4>'    .    $row['caseName']    .    '</h4>';
            echo    "</div>";
            echo    "</div>";
            echo    "<div    class='row'>";
            echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
            echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
            echo    "</div>";
            echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
            echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
            echo    "</div>";
            echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
            echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
            echo    "</div>";
            echo    "</div>";
    
         $i++;
    }

 }
```

Comment: the if conditional is redundant since the while loop block will never execute if the result set is 0.

Comment: @halabuda see the OP question carefully `<div    class='case'    id='case$i'>`, OP is using $i value for id so thats why I used $i variable and it is a best practice to check if data is present or not. If you read the question properly you might not comment like this.

Comment: @halabuda read my edited comments - it is a best practice to check if data is present or not. If it is not OP can print `result not found` in else condition

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply as it was exactly what I was after. however i get an error: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

Comment: @rakesh-shetty point taken. FYI mysql_fetch_assoc will fail given a mysqli result resource.

Comment: @user248305 change it to mysqli_fetch_assoc and you should be fine.

Comment: @user248305 Sorry, there was a typo, change to  `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `while` or `foreach`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxx","xxx");
//    Check    connection
if    (mysqli_connect_errno())    {
echo    "Failed    to    connect    to    MySQL:    "    .    mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result    =    mysqli_query($con,"SELECT    *    FROM    caseStudies");
$i=1;
while($row    =    mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo    "<div    class='case'    id='case$i'>";
echo    "<div    class='row'>";
echo    "<div    class='header'>";
echo    '<h4>'    .    $row['caseName']    .    '</h4>';
echo    "</div>";
echo    "</div>";
echo    "<div    class='row'>";
echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
echo    "</div>";
echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
echo    "</div>";
echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
echo    "</div>";
echo    "</div>";
$i++;               
}
?>
```

Comment: can I also somehow keep my logic for echo "<div class='case' id='case$i'>"; within this loop? I am struggling to figure out how

Comment: do you have a autoincrement primary key for the table? if yes you can add it by echo "<div class='case' id='".$row[0]."'>"; or echo "<div class='case' id='".$row['case_id']."'>";

Comment: or you just need it to be serial numbers you can do it like my answer. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance you should use a WHILE loop, like so:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxx","xxx");
//    Check    connection
if    (mysqli_connect_errno())    {
  echo    "Failed    to    connect    to    MySQL:    "    .    mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result    =    mysqli_query($con,"SELECT    *    FROM    caseStudies");
$i=0;
while($row    =    mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo    "<div    class='case'    id='case$i++'>";
  echo    "<div    class='row'>";
  echo    "<div    class='header'>";
  echo    '<h4>'    .    $row['caseName']    .    '</h4>';
  echo    "</div>";
  echo    "</div>";
  echo    "<div    class='row'>";
  echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
  echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
  echo    "</div>";
  echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
  echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
  echo    "</div>";
  echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
  echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
  echo    "</div>";
  echo    "</div>";
}
```

You COULD use a for loop if you really wanted/needed to by replacing the 1 in the comparative portion of your for loop with the mysqli_num_rows() function as such:

```
for($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$countRes = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for($i=0; $i<$countRes; $i++){ ... }
```

Use `mysqli_num_rows($result)` for getting the number of record count.

Answer (score 0):

**Use :** `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

**Instead of:** `for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `while` loop as other people said to do this for each rows

(while will stop and the last row automatically, you don't need to know the number of rows you have)

if you want do it just twice, keep your code BUT : you have a **missing `</div>`**

**EDIT :** it seems your edit have corrected the missing `</div>`